# How to disable caching of jsp (and static resources) at META-INF/resources in Tomcat 7 (servlet 3.0)?

Tags: tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I've tried to set the cachingAllowed to false at both context.xml and server.xml. 
And I use the default Context (org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext). 
But Tomcat still ignores modifications in dependencies jars within WEB-INF/lib (changes in jsp or js at META-INF/resources have no results).
I've tried to delete the Work folder with no success.

Dos anyone knows a way to turn off this caching? 
This is for dev purpose of quickly change the resources (jsp reloading) and see the result without restart Tomcat.
I used to use war overlays and I am trying to migrate to servlet 3.0.

Comment: A quick look at the source code suggests that there might be a Tomcat bug here. Let me do some digging.

Comment: I've dug into the source code and added a test case to confirm that Tomcat's behaviour is correct. If the context has caching disabled then static resources are not cached. You'll need to provide more information (exact Tomcat version, configuration details, etc.) for folks to help you further.

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for ur reply!.Should this work also for JSPs since they are not static?Is there any way to achieve that? Can you tell me which class to look?

Comment: BTW, we are trying this on tomcat 7.0.42.